# Passport.js User Login & Authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

For the past few days I have been developing my first User login & authentication system using Passport.js. Awkwardly enough, I have finished it and it works just as intended. The problem is, even though I have read a lot of articles and checked tens of examples online, I seem to not completely understand the code per se. I have no issues understanding the process behind it and why it has to happen like that. I would really appreciate it if you could clarify some parts of the code for me. This is the working code, stored in my app.js file:

```
// Passport session setup
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

// Use the Local Strategy within passport
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }

        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user: ' + username});
        }

        user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }

            if (isMatch) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid Password' });
            }
        });
    });
}));

var app = module.exports = express();

app.configure(function () {
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname + '/views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.engine('html', hbs.__express);
    app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'xxx' }));    
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));

});
```

I am using MongoDB (User - mongoose model). Also, to store passwords in the database I am currently using bcrypt.

I think that the most critical part that I do not understand here is the **done** callback function. I can understand that it simply passes some values, and I know that much to realize that the first parameter of it is the error and the second the data. Still, I do not fully grasp it because I haven't specifically provided one as a parameter. For example, if I would have a function like this:

```
// Random Function
var randomFunction = function (a, b, done) {
    done(a, b);
};

// Then I would call the randomFunction providing my own **done**
randomFunction('Random', 'Words', function(a, b) { return a + b; });
```

Still, in my example I am not the one specifying the **done** callback. Is it simply a required callback function parameter or is it the same as the next function in a normal middleware such as:

```
function middleware (req, res, next) {
    next(req.user); // pass the req.user to next middleware
}
```

Also, where does Passport.js bind the user that it handles? Does it bind it to **req.user**? And how can I pass it to certain views in order, for example, to display the username?

I am looking forward to your feedback!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Done callback**

Look at the code of [Local Strategy](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L42):

```
function Strategy(options, verify) {
  ...
  this._verify = verify;
  ...
}
```

`verify` is the function that will be used by strategy to verify a user and you've specified it here:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
    // your verification code here
}));
```

Later in strategy you can find [authenticate](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L90) method that calls verify function from the step above:

```
this._verify(username, password, verified);
```

So, you now see where `username`, `password` and `done==verified` come from. Later in your code you will call the `done` callback with (err, user, info) arguments. In a few words, `done` is needed to finish asynchronous procedure of user verification.

**req.user and views**

Yes, you are right about `req.user`. So you can pass it to your views by two ways:

1. As an argument of `res.render` function. [See docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render)

   ```
   res.render('some-template', { name: req.user });
   ```
2. Use `res.locals` as some kind of context provider (now user object will be available in all the views that are defined in `app.router`). [See docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals)

   ```
   // before app.use(app.router);
   app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.locals.user = req.user;
      next();
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback! As I understand it, done is a callback function used to return the information from the middleware. By information I mean the 3 parameters (err, user, info). Basically, could I consider the done callback as being (in a high-level way) the return of that specific middleware?

Comment: If I understood your question in a right way, no. `done` is only used to provide some data to the next level. Your verification code will be executed in normal way after calling `done()`, that is why you should use `return done(err);` to stop executing you verification code. It is common case for async stuff.

Comment: That is what I meant ^^ I think I was a bit ambiguous in my answer :) Thanks a lot for your feedback, I really appreciate it!